# Wieso muss »es« in diesem Satz stehen?

Tags: sentence-structure, pronoun, expletiva

> Ich mag **es**, Deutsch zu lesen.
>   I like to read German.

Wieso benutzen viele Muttersprachler ein »*es*« vor dem Nomen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es ist zu hoffen, dass alle Muttersprachler es an jener Stelle verwenden. Es gehört da nämlich hin. Es auszulassen ist falsch.

So viele *es* im vorigen Absatz! Deutsch verwendet das Ersatzsubjekt/-objekt *es* manchmal auch an Stellen, an denen Englisch es auslässt. (Ich gehe wegen deines Beispiels davon aus, dass du die Verwendung im Englischen gewohnt bist.)

> *Es* ist zu hoffen, …

*One must/has to hope …*

Hier ist es ein Ersatzsubjekt. **Was** ist zu hoffen? Antwort: **Es**. Englisch verwendet hier *one* als Ersatzsubjekt, weil nur Personen hoffen können. Im Deutschen ist es hingegen immer *es*. Es tritt an die Stelle von nichts.

> dass alle Muttersprachler es an jener Stelle verwenden.

*all native speakers use it at that place.*

Hier ist *es* ein Ersatzobjekt. Es tritt an die Stelle des thematisierten Objekts aus dem vorhergehenden Satz. Genau wie im Englischen.

> Es gehört da nämlich hin.

*It belongs there.*

Wieder ein Ersatzsubjekt. Hier verwendet Englisch ebenfalls *it*.

> Es auszulassen ist falsch.

*To omit it is wrong.*

Hier ist *es* wiederum ein Ersatzobjekt. **Wen oder Was** auszulassen ist falsch? Antwort: **Es**. Und auch hier macht es das Englische ganz genauso.

---

Was ist an deinem Beispiel anders? Du verwendest einen Infinitiv als Objekt. Das geht im Deutschen wie im Englischen. Im Deutschen muss der Infinitiv dazu aber zum Substantiv erklärt werden. Das geschieht durch Großschreibung.

> Ich mag Lesen.

*I like to read.*

Leider kann man **das Lesen** so nicht weiter verfeinern. Versuche nicht, an dieser Stelle ein selbst ausgedachtes zusammengesetztes Substantiv einzusetzen. Es ist zwar nicht falsch, klingt aber furchtbar holprig.

> Ich mag *Deutschlesen*. **(SCHLECHT!)**

Es geht, wenn eine Tätigkeit idiomatisch geworden ist:

> Ich mag Kaffeetrinken. (das Kaffeetrinken == tea time)

Stattdessen benutzt du **es**.

> Ich mag es. (**Wen oder Was** magst du?)

*I like it.*

Antwort:

> Deutsch zu lesen.

*To read German.*